# How to debug stored procedures in SQL server 2008 without CLR?

Tags: sql-server, debugging

How can I debug stored procedures in SQL Server 2008 management studio?

I am trying to put a break point on SQL query and then press start debugging but I get an error that debugging cannot be started on my machine:

```
Debug cannot be started at <machine name>.
```

I don't want to use CLR debugging.  How can I debug stored procedures?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Type `exec YourStoredProcedure`. Put break point next to it. Hit green (debug) arrow next to execute button. Debugger should start and hit your break point. Hit F11 to step into your stored procedure. 
See debug menu for more options.

Here is very detailed blog post: [T-SQL Debugger for SQL Server 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/billramo/archive/2009/04/11/transact-sql-debugger-for-sql-server-2008-part-1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

**try with**

```
TRY()... CATCH()... METHOD
```

Read the hints online based on your SP