# How to debug SQL CLR stored procedures function on SQL Server 2012 from VS 2012

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, debugging, visual-studio-2012

How does one step through code SQL CLR  through VS 2012?

I'm trying to read my code line by line and see hoe my calculations work but when I put a break point in my application and try to step through I can't it just ignores it.

I have already tried many solutions given on the net by MSDN and Stack Overflow: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993380/how-to-debug-stored-procedures-in-sql-server-2008-without-clr?rq=1) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016417/how-to-debug-sql-server-t-sql-in-visual-studio-2012?lq=1) [3](http://sqlmag.com/visual-studio-2010/debugging-stored-procedures-visual-studio-2010) [4](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b93bb4c8-1383-4542-9361-db1c111b1040/debugging-sql-clr-stored-procedures-with-vs2012-and-sql-server-2008r2) [And a whole lot more](https://www.google.com/search?q=debugging+sql+server+stored+procedure&oq=debugging+Sql&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0j69i60j0l3.7605j0&sourceid=chrome&espvd=208&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)
 but I can't seem to solve my problem.

Comment: Unless you tell us what actual solutions you've tried, people may end up just wasting their (and your) time posting solutions you've already tried, or not posting solutions you've not tried, on the assumption that such a solution is obvious/easily findable on the internet, and thus you *must* have already tried them.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever sorry  - [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016417/how-to-debug-sql-server-t-sql-in-visual-studio-2012) including linked qustions and the MSDN webstite ralating to the above question.